# How to reset folder permissions in .NET?

Tags: .net, folder-permissions

I have a program that needs to change the permissions on specified folder. What I must do first is to remove any permission that was given to the folder by inheritance (i.e. remove all actuel permission) and add new permissions for specifics users/groups.

I know I can easily remove a permission for a folder for a specific user when I know that user, but is there a way to wipe all permission so that I can start fresh or do I need to find a way to find all existing permission and then remove them one by one ?

What I need to do more specifically is to create a new folder WITHOUT the inherited permissions and set my own.

To be more specific, I would like to do as though I created the directory then I went into security, advanced and removed the inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've been doing some test and what I needed to do is called the SetAccessRuleProtection method from the DirectorySecurity and apply it to my DirectoryInfo.

I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if will do everthing you need but those are the .NET tool

[Directory.GetAccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getaccesscontrol.aspx)

[Directory.SetAccessControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setaccesscontrol.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Not strictly in .NET, but you can use the `ICACLS` program with `Process.Start()` like this:

```
Process.Start("icacls MyDir /inheritance:r");
```

Comment: I don't know if I can use DOS command in this program. Isn't there a way to do it with code ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a program that does the same thing

```
Private Sub AddPermisssion(ByVal directories As String)
    Dim AccountingPermFolder As String = directories
    Dim AccountingDI As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(AccountingPermFolder) 
    Dim AccountingDS As DirectorySecurity = AccountingDI.GetAccessControl
    AccountingDS.SetAccessRuleProtection(True, False) //True Protect file and False remove Inheritance   
    IO.Directory.SetAccessControl(AccountingPermFolder, AccountingDS)

    AccountingDS.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(Admins, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))
    AccountingDS.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(AccountGroup, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))
    AccountingDS.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(SystemAdmin, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow))
    AccountingDI.SetAccessControl(AccountingDS)


End Sub
```